# Create an empty file in a directory which may or may not exist

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make a shell script that creates an empty file as /data/app/log/app.log.pos. The /data/app/log/ dir may or may not exist. If it does not exist, it should create it.

When the path does not exist, and I run

```
sudo cat > /data/app/log/app.log.pos
```

I get

```
-bash: /data/game/log/app.log.pos: No such file or directory
```

Furthermore, even if `/data/app/` exists but the `log` folder doesn't, I get a similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir -p /data/app/log/
> /data/app/log/app.log.pos
```

If you need to use `sudo`, you should `sudo` the entire script. It's a good practice to avoid putting `sudo` calls into scripts. Instead, the person who invokes the script is the one who should call `sudo`.

But if you really want to do `sudo` in the script, do something like:

```
mkdir -p /data/app/log/
sudo rm /data/app/log/app.log.pos       # optional
sudo touch /data/app/log/app.log.pos
```

Comment: thanks, one little thingie. if I run the second line, it tells me: "
/data/app/log/app.log.pos: Permission denied". It would suffice to write "sudo > /data/app/log/app.log.pos" to avoid this?

Comment: @adriancdperu No, that won't work. `sudo` doesn't apply to redirections. See my edit.